# Numbered equations in itemize

Tags: equations, itemize, ragged2e

I want to list some equations in an itemize environment and still use the corresponding equation numbers. For that I defined

```
\newcommand\inlineeqno{\stepcounter{equation}\ (\theequation)}
```

and then i use

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item $equation...$ \inlineeqno
\end{itemize}.
```

While this works in principle, I want the equation number to be located at the right, like the other numbers. However, using `\raggedleft` aligns the whole list and `flushright` gives a new paragraph.

Any idea how to do this?

Moreover, how can I define a label and refer to a particular equation in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem so I found your question when I was looking for solutions.

First of all, using \hspace*{\fill} you can aling the equation's number to de right:

```
\newcommand\inlineeqno{\stepcounter{equation}\ \hspace*{\fill} (\theequation)}
```

For your second question, I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361785/282056). That's my final code:

```
 \newcommand{\inlineeqnum}{\refstepcounter{equation}~~ \hspace*{\fill} \mbox{(\theequation)}}
```

In this example I labeled the second equation:

```
 \begin{itemize}
   \item $equation...$  \inlineeqnum
   \item $equation2...$ \inlineeqnum \label{eq:example}
   \item $equation...$  \inlineeqnum
 \end{itemize}.

 As we can see in \eqref{eq:example}, ...
```